# Ruby on Rails: Show results on page, after search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, parameters

I am trying to hide my search results until after the search has happened. At the moment when I click from the home page to the search page, the page shows the search boxes, but also shows all of the database in a table. I am wanting to just show the search options, and search button, then depending on the search, show the right table.

Here is my search view:

```
<h1>Search</h1>

<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>

Client :
<%= select(@projects, :client, Project.all.map {|p| [p.client]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:client]) %></br>

Industry :
<%= select(@projects, :industry, Project.all.map {|p| [p.industry]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:industry]) %></br>

Role :
<%= select(@projects, :role, Project.all.map {|p| [p.role]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:role]) %></br>

Technologies :
<%= select(@projects, :tech, Project.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:tech]) %></br>

Business Division :

<%= select(@projects, :business_div, Project.all.map {|p| [p.business_div]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:business_div]) %></br>

Project Owner :
<%= select(@projects, :project_owner, Project.all.map {|p| [p.project_owner]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:project_owner]) %></br>

Exception PM
<%= select(@projects, :exception_pm, Project.all.map {|p| [p.exception_pm]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:exception_pm]) %></br>


Start Date :

<%=  text_field_tag("start_date") %></br>


End Date :

<%= text_field_tag("end_date") %></br>


Status :

<%= select(@projects, :status, Project.all.map {|p| [p.status]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:status]) %></br>

Keywords :

<%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %></br>

<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>

<% end %>


<% if @search %>
    <h3><%=@project_search.total_entries%> results</h3>
<% end %>

<% if @search %>
<table class = "pretty">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "project_name", "Project name" %> </th>
    <th><%= sortable "client", "Client" %></th>
    <th>Exception pm</th>
    <th>Project owner</th>
    <th>Tech</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Industry</th>
    <th>Financials</th>
    <th>Business div</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>End date</th>
<% if false %>
    <th>Entry date</th>
    <th>Edited date</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th>Lessons learned</tStackh>
    <th>Customer benifits</th>
    <th>Keywords</th>
    <!th></th>
    <!th></th>
    <!th></th>
<% end %>
  </tr>

<%# end %>

<% @project_search.each do |t| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= t.project_name %></td>
    <td><%= t.client %></td>
    <td><%= t.exception_pm %></td>
    <td><%= t.project_owner %></td>
    <td><%= t.tech %></td>
    <td><%= t.role %></td>
    <td><%= t.industry %></td>
    <td><%= t.financials %></td>
    <td><%= t.business_div %></td>
    <td><%= t.status %></td>
    <td><%= l t.start_date %></td>
    <td><%= l t.end_date %></td>
<% if false %>
    <td><%= t.entry_date %></td>
    <td><%= t.edited_date %></td>
    <td><%= t.summary %></td>
    <td><%= t.lessons_learned %></td>
    <td><%= t.customer_benifits %></td>
    <td><%= t.keywords %></td>
<% end %>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Show', project %></td>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

Results per page: <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,20,50], params[:per_page].to_i), :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>

<br />
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :per_page, params[:per_page] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :page, params[:page] %>
<%= will_paginate (@project_search) %>


<%= button_to "Search Again?", search_path, :method => "get" %>

<%# end %>
<%= button_to "Home", projects_path, :method => "get" %>
```

Here is the search action:

```
def search


@search = params[:client], params[:industry], params[:role], params[:tech], params[:business_div], params[:project_owner], params[:exception_pm], params[:status], params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:keywords]

@project_search = Project.search(@search)

   @project = Project.new(params[:project])

respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

and here is my model.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech

validates_presence_of :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :end_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech





def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, search_tech, search_business_div, search_project_owner, search_exception_pm, search_status, search_start_date, search_end_date, search_keywords) 
  return scoped unless search_client.present? || search_industry.present? || search_role.present? || search_tech.present? || search_business_div.present? || search_project_owner.present? || search_exception_pm.present? || search_status.present? || search_start_date.present? || search_end_date.present? || search_keywords.present?

if search_start_date != ""
search_start_date = Date.parse(search_start_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end
if search_end_date != ""
search_end_date = Date.parse(search_end_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end



  where(['client LIKE ? AND industry LIKE ? AND role LIKE ? AND tech LIKE ? AND business_div LIKE ? AND project_owner LIKE ? AND exception_pm LIKE ? AND status LIKE ? AND start_date LIKE ? AND end_date LIKE ? AND keywords LIKE ?', "%#{search_client}%", "%#{search_industry}%" , "%#{search_role}%" , "%#{search_tech}%" , "%#{search_business_div}%" , "%#{search_project_owner}%" , "%#{search_exception_pm}%" , "%#{search_status}%", "%#{search_start_date}%", "%#{search_end_date}%","%#{search_keywords}%"])



end


def self.paginated_for_index(projects_per_page, current_page)
    paginate(:per_page => projects_per_page, :page => current_page)
  end

end
```

Hopefully you can see what I have tried to do. I am getting the error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 11)` as I haven't split the params. But when I use `*@search` I get loads of errors.

My original code in the controller looked like this before I went about trying to hide the table:

`@project_search = Project.search(params[:client], params[:industry], params[:role], params[:tech], params[:business_div], params[:project_owner], params[:exception_pm], params[:status], params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:keywords]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page`)

Comment: What's the result of the code that you're currently running? Error? Unexpected output?

Comment: wrong number of arguments (1 for 11)

Comment: Why don't you put all these parameters in only one hash with subhashes, using `form_for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to splat the `@search` params when passing it to `.search` to tell Ruby to expand your array of arguments to separate arguments to be passed to `Project.search`

```
@project_search = Project.search(*@search)
```

[Information on using splat](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/)

**Edit** *(to answer your follow-up question)*

Testing with

```
<% if @search %>
```

isn't enough because it will always have a value that evaluates to `true`, even if its just `[]` or `["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]`. One way to check this properly would be to create a new boolean instance variable that is `true` if all fields are blank in the search filters.

```
# put this after you set @search in your action
@search_performed = !@search.reject! { |c| c.blank? }.empty?
```

and now test `@search_performed` in your view with

```
<% if @search_performed %>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why to use `*` instead to just passe `params` in argument? Could you give an example of the `search` function?

Comment: OP says the error is `wrong number of arguments (1 for 11)`, meaning he's passing 1 argument in when the `search` function is expecting **11**. `@search` contains an array of arguments which he's passing to `Project.search`. What he intends to do is pass the 11 elements in the `@search` array as independent arguments. That's where `*` comes in.

Comment: all sorts of errors happen when I use *@search. I will edit my question, so that you get a better idea of what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the help

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the errors I was getting. I am now getting none, however, nothing has changed when I try to hid the table before the search. Still shows when I load the search page.
I used `<% if @search %>` to check if a search has been tried.

Comment: Updated my answer for your follow-up question.

Comment: Thanks for that. Works perfectly, except now the user can't search on all fields as blank to bring up the whole database. Can you think of a clever way around this?

Comment: This is outside the scope of the original question, but I imagine testing the size of `@project_search` would be another way. You could add `|| @project_search.size > 0` to the `@search_performed` assignment.

Comment: That undid the suggestion you gave me earlier. `|| @project_search.size > 0` showed the whole database again, when I accessed the search page.

Answer (score 0):

you are storing array in `@search` and u have to use `*` operator

```
@project_search = Project.search(*@search)
```

Comment: I got alot of different errors when trying your suggestion. I have edited my OP so you can get a better idea of what I'm trying to do, and what's going wrong. thanks